# Issue with image uploading PHP

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I'm trying to create a form where users can select an image and set their profile picture. After this I want to get this specific information and display it within HTML.

I have the following code inside profile.php;

```
if(isset($_POST['submit']) ){
    $fileName = $_FILES["avatar"]["name"];
    $fileTmpLoc = $_FILES["avatar"]["tmp_name"];
    $fileType = $_FILES["avatar"]["type"];
    $fileSize = $_FILES["avatar"]["size"];
    $fileErrorMsg = $_FILES["avatar"]["error"];
    $mysql->setUserAvatar($fileName, $fileTmpLoc, $fileType, $fileSize, $fileErrorMsg, $s_email);
}
```

I have the following code inside mysql.php (this code is inside a class name mysql):

```
function setUserAvatar($fileName, $fileTmpLoc, $fileType, $fileSize, $fileErrorMsg, $s_email){

    $kaboom = explode(".", $fileName);
    $fileExt = end($kaboom);

    list($width, $height) = getimagesize($fileTmpLoc);

    if($width < 10 || $height < 10){
        echo "Image is too small";
        exit(); 
    }

    $db_file_name = rand(100000000000,999999999999) . "." . $fileExt;
    echo $db_file_name;

    if($fileSize > 1048576) {
        echo "Image can't be larger than 1MB";
        exit(); 
    } else if (!preg_match("/\.(gif|jpg|png)$/i", $fileName) ) {
        echo "The file extension should be .gif, .jpg or .png";
        exit();
    } else if ($fileErrorMsg == 1) {
        echo "An unknown error occurred";
        exit();
    }

    $sql = "SELECT avatar FROM users WHERE email='$s_email' LIMIT 1";

    $query = mysqli_query($this->db, $sql);
    $row = mysqli_fetch_row($query);

    $avatar = $row[0];

    if($avatar != ""){
        $picurl = "../user/$s_email/$avatar"; 
        if (file_exists($picurl)) { unlink($picurl); }
    } 

    $moveResult = move_uploaded_file($fileTmpLoc, SITE_ROOT . "/../user/$s_email/". $db_file_name);

    if ($moveResult != true) {
        echo "File upload failed";
        exit();
    }

    $sql = "UPDATE users SET avatar='$db_file_name' WHERE email='$s_email' LIMIT 1";
    $query = mysqli_query($this->db, $sql);

}
```

After this is done, I want to do something like:

```
<img src="user/" . $s_email . "/" . $data['avatar'] . " />
```

How ever, when I try to reach the avatar element from the MySQL database, I always get the same number, which is: 2147483647 (but in the user folder everything went right). So there is a problem with the value that is getting inserted into the database. Any suggestions what this problem might be?

**EDIT: I've fixed the issue by decreasing the length of the random number. However, the problem is still that the value in the database hasn't receive the extension? The column datatype of avatar is VARCHAR.**

It's this line:

```
$db_file_name = rand(100000,999999) . "." . $fileExt;
```

Comment: What do you mean by the table is an charset?  What is the DataType of the file name column?

Comment: I'm sorry, I ment the avatar column datatype is a varchar.

Comment: I'd do some hard coded tests to find the nature of the problem, see what happens if the file name is short like 1.jpeg, or try starting the file name with a character to better narrow down the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, a nice feature of most random number generators is that they produce repeatable results unless you tell them not to.

In the case of PHP you tell it not to start at the same place using [srand()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.srand.php)

Comment: Well, that's actually not the case, because the images that are uploaded within the user/$s_email folder are correctly generated. The problem is that the values inside the 'avatar' tables are all 2147483647 (and without an extension).

Comment: You're saying that the value of $db_file_name changes between the 6th last line in the function and the last line without ever being set?

Comment: Yes, the values difference, while the $db_file_name is not changed.

Comment: Not possible. Your analysis is wrong. It's improbable that the variable magically changed its value without being set via the code, hence either the code you've shown us is not the code you are using, or at least one the two lines of code did not execute correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Your number is to big.  and not very random.

```
$db_file_name = rand(100000000000,999999999999)
```

Your min and max are very close to each other/in wrong order, and to large because the number your getting `2147483647 = 2^30 -1`  is most likely the size limit for the type of column input you decided to use for the name.

rand documentation http://php.net/manual/en/function.rand.php

Change your column type to something like varchar(40)

I'd also recommend not using random numbers greater than php's signed 32 bit integer  `rand(0,2147483647);`